# WP Как дополнить или модифицировать блок Featured image?

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg

Есть стандартный блок `Изображения записи` поста в админке. Необходимо добавить в данный блок ещё 2 поля изображений для мобильного и планшетного отображения на фронтовой части в теге `<picture>`. Вопрос - как это реализовать ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поскольку используюються современная тема с Gutenberg блоками, то стандартный вариант по типу.

```
function custom_featured_image_field() {
    ?>
    <div class="custom-featured-image-field">
        <label for="custom-featured-image">Custom Featured Image:</label>
        <input type="text" id="custom-featured-image" name="custom_featured_image" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'custom_featured_image', true)); ?>">
        <button class="button" onclick="openMediaUploader()">Select Image</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        function openMediaUploader() {
            var mediaUploader = wp.media({
                title: 'Select Image',
                multiple: false
            });

            mediaUploader.on('select', function () {
                var attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                jQuery('#custom-featured-image').val(attachment.url);
            });

            mediaUploader.open();
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}

function save_custom_featured_image_field($post_id) {
    if (isset($_POST['custom_featured_image'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_featured_image', esc_url($_POST['custom_featured_image']));
    }
}

function add_custom_featured_image_field() {
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function () {
        wp_enqueue_media();
    });
    add_action('admin_footer', 'custom_featured_image_field');
    add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_featured_image_field');
}

add_action('admin_init', 'add_custom_featured_image_field');
```

Не работает... Я понимаю, что здесь необходим подход с созданием `React` элемента, но неужели, в новом редакторе WP не предусмотрено разширения готового функционала, а надо именно отключать стандартный и создавать новый ? Или есть решение проще ?
*Мне неодходимо именно добавить в текущую вкладку `Featured image` новые поля изображений, не затрагивая текущие настройки, на которые ориентируються сторонние плагины.

Comment: Вроде можно расширить посредством пакета `@wordpress/hooks` и фильтра [editor.BlockEdit](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#editor-blockedit) можно будет добавить необходимые controls в существующий core компонент, это не требует удаления стандартного блока.

Comment: Спасибо, а можна подробнее, ато я не понимаю куда именно это вставлять. Можно ли как-то это держать в теме сайта, не создавая дополнительных плагинов и не подключая node-modules ?

Comment: Ладно, полез я попробовать и все же именно существующую панель Featured Image расширить не выйдет. Фильтр будет работать только с Gutenberg Block Featured Image но не с сайд панелью. WordPress не предоставляет методов для расширения существующей боковой панели Featured Image и фактически, можно либо ее действительно удалить и добавить свою кастомную сайд панель со всеми полями или не удалять существующую а добавить так же дополнительную панель, но с меньшим количеством полей.